# Count lines based on header and date

Tags: perl

i have a tab separated file with this format:

```
Business System Name:  OK_CR                      

Serial Numbr  Service Name          Program Name          Epoch Start Time     
------------  --------------------  --------------------  -------------------  
GI1001TAA266  PPV 10 (50106)        We Bought A Zoo       Aug 14 2012  4:15AM  
GI1002TB3596  PPV 5 (50101)         Help, The (2011)      Aug 14 2012  6:30PM  
GI1002TDH825  PPV 2 (50098)         Safe House            Sep  7 2012  2:15AM  

Business System Name:  OK_SV                      

Serial Numbr  Service Name          Program Name          Epoch Start Time     
------------  --------------------  --------------------  -------------------  
GI1001TAA266  PPV 10 (50106)        We Bought A Zoo       Aug 14 2012  4:15AM  
GI1002TB3596  PPV 5 (50101)         Help, The (2011)      Aug 14 2012  6:30PM  
GI1002TDH825  PPV 2 (50098)         Safe House            Sep  7 2012  2:15AM
```

I want to count the number of lines by date separated by the business system header, i mean the result of the script should be like this:

```
Business System Name:  OK_CR
Aug 14: 2
Sep 7: 1

Business System Name:  OK_SV
Aug 14: 2
Sep 7: 1
```

So far I have created a hash but I'm struck on how to count each date and reset the counter after each business system header. This is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

open my $fh, '<', 'ppv.txt' or die $!;

my %data;
my $sect;
while (<$fh>) {
  next if /^\s+/;
  if (/^Business System Name:\s+(\w+)/) {
    $sect = $1;
    next;
  }
  #print "$sect\n";
  if (defined $sect) {
    next if /^Serial Numbr/;
    next if /^------------/;
    push @{ $data{$sect} }, $_;
  }
}
print Dumper \%data;
```

This is the result of the script:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'OK_CR' => [
                       'GI1001TAA266  PPV 10 (50106)        We Bought A Zoo       Aug 14 2012  4:15AM
',
                       'GI1002TB3596  PPV 5 (50101)         Help, The (2011)      Aug 14 2012  6:30PM
',
                       'GI1002TDH825  PPV 2 (50098)         Safe House            Sep  7 2012  2:15AM
'
                     ],
          'OK_SV' => [
                       'GI1001TAA266  PPV 10 (50106)        We Bought A Zoo       Aug 14 2012  4:15AM
',
                       'GI1002TB3596  PPV 5 (50101)         Help, The (2011)      Aug 14 2012  6:30PM
',
                       'GI1002TDH825  PPV 2 (50098)         Safe House            Sep  7 2012  2:15AM
'
                     ]
        };
```

Any idea on how to advance from here?

Comment: Are there 4 fields in the date-containing lines? If so, you need to capture the fourth field, split it up to get the date format you need, and then use `my %count;` before the loop; `$count{$date}++;` in place of the `push`. In the 'Business System Name' section, you print out the previous business details and the dates/counts (if there was one), then empty the  hash (`%clear = ();`).  At the end, you print out the previous business details too (if there was one).

Comment: yes they are lines  i found in google this ways to extract the fourth field:  my $format = 'A57 A13 A*'; my($prefixes, $date, $suffixes) = unpack( $format, $_ );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `unpack`, as in your comment, you just need to keep track of the number for each date:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

open my $fh, '<', 'ppv.txt' or die $!;

my %data;
my $sect;
while (<$fh>) {
  next if /^\s+/;
  if (/^Business System Name:\s+(\w+)/) {
    $sect = $1;
    next;
  }
  #print "$sect\n";
  if (defined $sect) {
    next if /^Serial Numbr/;
    next if /^------------/;
    my $format = 'A57 A13 A*';
    my($prefixes, $date, $suffixes) = unpack($format, $_);
    $data{$sect}{$date}++;
  }
}
print Dumper \%data;

__END__

$VAR1 = {
          'OK_CR' => {
                       ' Aug 14 2012' => 2,
                       ' Sep  7 2012' => 1
                     },
          'OK_SV' => {
                       ' Aug 14 2012' => 2,
                       ' Sep  7 2012' => 1
                     }
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash =();
open(FILE,"test.txt");
while(<FILE>)
{
    if(/(Business System Name:\s+OK_\S+)\s+/)
    {
        if(%hash)
        {
            print Dumper \%hash;
            %hash=();
            $hash{header}=$1;
        }
        else
        {
            $hash{header}=$1;
        }
    }
    elsif(/((Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s+\d+\s+\d\d\d\d)/)
    {
        if(defined $hash{$1}){$hash{$1}++;}
        else{$hash{$1}=1;}
    }
}
close(FILE);
if(%hash)
{
    print Dumper \%hash;
}
```

output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Aug 14 2012' => 2,
          'Sep  7 2012' => 1,
          'header' => 'Business System Name:  OK_CR'
        };
$VAR1 = {
          'Aug 14 2012' => 2,
          'Sep  7 2012' => 1,
          'header' => 'Business System Name:  OK_SV'
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option that sets Perl's record separator (`$/`) to 'Business System Name:' so your file's read in those chunks as records.  It also `split`s the date lines on `\t` since your file contains tab-separated data:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

local $/ = 'Business System Name:';
my %data;

while (<>) {
    my ($sect) = /\s+(.+)/;
    my @timeLines = grep /:\d\d(?:A|P)M$/, split /\n/;
    for (@timeLines) {
        ( split /\t/ )[-1] =~ /(.+?)\s+\d+:/;
        $data{$sect}{$1}++;
    }
}

print Dumper \%data
```

Usage: `perl script.pl inFile [>outFile]`

The last, optional parameter directs output to a file.

Output on your dataset:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'OK_SV                      ' => {
                                             'Aug 14 2012' => 2,
                                             'Sep  7 2012' => 1
                                           },
          'OK_CR                      ' => {
                                             'Aug 14 2012' => 2,
                                             'Sep  7 2012' => 1
                                           }
        };
```

After a record is read, the section name is captured.  Next, the lines of the record are `split` on newlines, and are `grep`ped for only those lines which contain time data.  The last `for` loop `split`s on the tab character, gets the last field, captures the date information, and then increments the hash with the sect and date data.

Hope this helps!